# How to convert GTFS to XML or JSON?

Tags: google-maps-api, xml, json, general-transit-feed-specification

Do you know any tool that provides that? I need to manipulated GTFS file but I would like to have data available in any well-known format like XML or JSON.

EDIT

GTFS are [Google Transit Feed Specification](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/)

Comment: GTFS is this: https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/ or something else? Edit your post and put a link in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone looking for something like this in 2014, take a look at [brendannee/node-gtfs - GitHub](https://github.com/brendannee/node-gtfs)

From the site's readme.md:

> node-GTFS loads transit data in GTFS format from GTFS Data Exchange, unzips it and stores it to a MongoDB database and provides some methods to query for agencies, routes, stops and times. It also has spatial queries to find nearby stops, routes and agencies.

node-GTFS is written in node.js, and the queries return data in JSON format.

Comment: If you want stops and routes in GeoJSON format, the gtfs-to-geojson project will convert GTFS to GeoJSON. https://github.com/blinktaginc/gtfs-to-geojson

Answer (score 0):

You can try these links [Mr. Data Converter](http://creativyst.com/Prod/15/)

[1](http://creativyst.com/Prod/15/): http://www.shancarter.com/data_converter/ or [Creativyst
CSV to XML](http://creativyst.com/Prod/15/)

Answer (score 0):

FME by Safe Software supports GTFS and JSON or XML output among numerous other possible output formats. 
http://www.safe.com/